# Show that for $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$, the central limit theorem holds

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $$P(X_n=n^{\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}=P(X_n=-n^\alpha),$$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that for $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$, the central limit theorem holds.

I understand that we have to show that the Lindeberg's version of CLT holds but I am having trouble verifying the Lindeberg's condition which is: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{s_n^2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(X_j^2\mathbb{I}_{|X_j|\ge\varepsilon s_n}\right)=0$$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $s_n=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}j^{2\alpha}}$. I understand that the main idea is to show that the Lindeberg's condition holds only if $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$ but I don't know how to proceed after this.

If someone could show me how to proceed after this or show me any easier way to approach this problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can estimate $s_n^2$ easily using integrals to over- and under-estimate the sum.

Comment: @whuber And how do we compute or deal with the sum of the expectations?

Comment: In the same way.  But first you have to evaluate the indicator and that requires an analysis of $s_n.$

Comment: Sorry, I'm too new to add a comment. Are you sure you have the question written down correctly? I don't think this satisfies the CLT if $\alpha = 10$ for example (and certainly $10 \geq - \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: @user1557414 I don't see why not. The idea is to find a $n_0(\varepsilon)$ such that for any $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$, and $n\ge n_0$, $n^{\alpha}<\varepsilon s_n$, which upon some analysis on $s_n$ won't be difficult to find.

Comment: In fact, for $\alpha\ge 0$, this is true for $n_0=1+\lceil \frac{2\alpha+1}{\varepsilon^2} \rceil$. And, I am sure it won't be difficult to find a $n_0$ for the case $-\frac{1}{2}\leq\alpha<0$ either.